# Reverse vertex winding order using matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I'm currently implementing reflections (Using the render-to-texture method), and so far it works, the only problem is that all objects in the reflected version are rendered inside out.

I'd like to avoid changing the internal OpenGL vertex winding order to make sure I don't interfere with other rendering operations too much.

Instead, I'd like to transform my reflection matrix to do the reversing. (Which should be just another reflection?)

This is my reflection matrix (which transforms the view matrix of the camera):

```
glm::mat4 matReflection(
    1.f -2.f *n.x *n.x,-2.f *n.x *n.y,-2.f *n.x *n.z,-2.f *n.x *d,
    -2.f *n.x *n.y,1.f -2.f *n.y *n.y,-2.f *n.y *n.z,-2.f *n.y *d,
    -2.f *n.x *n.z,-2.f *n.y *n.z,1.f -2.f *n.z *n.z,-2.f *n.z *d,
    0.f,0.f,0.f,1.f
);
```

n = normal of the plane of the reflection; d = distance of the plane

Is it even possible to reverse the vertex order through a matrix transformation? If so, how exactly?

Comment: Is your problem with the reversed winding order of the triangles, for example because you have backface culling enabled, or are using `gl_FrontFacing` in the shader? That would be hard to fix without changing the state for the winding order. Or is it with the direction of the normals? That could be addressed by applying the appropriate transformation to the normals.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a matrix to scale the y-axis by -1 after all other transformations (including projection), you will end up with an upside-down image (which you can use by including something like uv.y = 1-uv.y somewhere in your pipeline).

Comment: While scaling the Z-axis by **-1.0** would reverse the handedness (assuming no other axis is flipped), it actually would not change winding. The winding is determined using only X and Y in window-space, Z is irrelevant. If, on the other hand (no pun intended), you flipped X or Y it would do *both* change the handedness and winding. Changing the front-face orientation is probably the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the z-axis scaling not working. My first paragraph was also incorrect (I was thinking a bit sloppily about reflection matrices "turning models inside out"). I have found y-axis flipping useful though (if the scene might have a mixture of culling/winding modes).